# MariaDB not showing data when select * in mac terminal

Tags: xampp, mariadb

When I try to select * I get this from MariaDB :

[image]

But, when I select the food column individually, I see all the data :

[image]

What is going on here?

edit : Here are some more screens :

[image]

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: It's possible that the notes column has lots of trailing whitespace or some other unexpected data that causes the formatting to go wrong. Try inspecting the contents of each column until you see the formatting error appear.

Comment: @markusjm
Thanks for the reply, I added some more screens. I think the problem is in the notes column but I'm not sure why. 

I changed the data type to text for that column and still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The data came from a non-Mac source?  And it has a different type of line terminator?

Trim off trailing what space (Carriage Return / NewLine) *before* storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/) function to display the value without trailing and leading whitespace:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(notes, '^\\s*', ''), '\\s*$', '')
  FROM food1_test;
```

The inner `'^\\s*'` pattern matches all leading whitespace and the outer `'\\s*$'` pattern matches all trailing whitespace.

You can also do an in-place update of the data with the following SQL:

```
UPDATE food1_test SET
    notes = REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(notes, '^\\s*', ''), '\\s*$', '');
```

You could also use [`TRIM`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/trim/) but it only replaces a specific string and it wouldn't work with the non-space whitespace characters.

As was stated by Rick James, it is important to sanitize and clean up the input before putting it into a database.